# Camera to object distance

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

With three.js, given :

- A Camera `camera`
- An Object3D `yourObject`

How to find out the distance between the object and the camera ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make use of the `distanceTo()`-function:

`var distance = camera.position.distanceTo( yourObject.position );`

Comment: After working with Three.js a while, the distanceTo() function pops out to solve all my problems :-) Thanks

Comment: Working like a charm, using it on a globe to set marker cards `visible = false` when they are not visible to the camera calculating the distance between them and the camera, and removing visibility once the distance equals to the globe origin to camera distance